# How to handle conversion from string to enum when string starts with a number in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am receiving json from a server which I am converting to an object using Json.Net. For one member I am using the `StringEnumConverter` which works really perfect.

However all of a sudden the server decided to use strings which also can start with a number which results in a JsonSerilizationException - obviously because enums cannot start with a number in .Net.

Now I am trying to find a solution to handle that.My first approach was to add a "_" when Reading the Json (so my enums in the code would have a starting _ when they are followed by a number) and when writing the json I would delete the starting _ (if a number is following). To achieve this I copied the `StringEnumConverter` into my namespace and tried to change the according part in the `WriteJson` and `ReadJson` methods. However I cannot use the `StringEnumConverter` since there are other dependencies I cannot access in my own namespace.

Is there any elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you give some examples of the enums and the values you are recieving in your json

Comment: something like "2SomeEnum" -> _2SomeEnum. The first one is the actual value in the Json and the second one is the actual enum I am trying to get out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `JsonConverter` and trim the digits from the front

```
public class Json_34159840
{
    public static string JsonStr = @"{""enum"":""1Value"",""name"":""James"",""enum2"":""1""}";

    public static void ParseJson()
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new EnumConverter() }
        };

        // Later on...
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(JsonStr);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Enum);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Enum2);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
    }
}

public class EnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var str = value.ToString();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^_"))
        {
            writer.WriteValue(str.Substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(str);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = reader.Value.ToString();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^\d+$"))
        {
            return Enum.Parse(objectType, value);
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^\d+"))
        {
            value = "_" + value;
        }

        return Enum.Parse(objectType, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        //You might want to do a more specific check like
        //return objectType == typeof(JsonEnum);
        return objectType.IsEnum;
    }
}

public enum JsonEnum
{
    _0Default,
    _1Value
}

public class JsonClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JsonEnum Enum { get; set; }
    public JsonEnum Enum2 { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Added support for integers :D

Comment: Wow, I cannot verify that solution at the moment because I am on the road, but this looks as it make sense. I actually do not want to get rid of the beginning numbers I actually want to add something at the beginning to make it a valid `enum` (f.e. "_") but that is a no brainer. The only thing missing is the WriteJson because I need to Write the correct value back (this is why I cannot just delete the numbers). I am just wondering why this approach is so much easier (less complex) than the `StringEnumConverter` build in Json.Net.

Comment: No idea why it's easier but it does work.  I'll update it to keep the numbers :)

Comment: It seems that the regex does not match at all so now it always adds a "_" for each enum

Comment: It will match the regex if the value they send through is an integer, which is valid json for an enum.  See my example where enum2 is "1".

Comment: sorry it does not work with the regex you provided. I use this regex: `\b_+\w+` I also tried your regex on http://regexr.com/ with no match using your values. Anyway you brought me on the right path, I am gonna edit your solution to complete it.

Comment: http://regexr.com/ Does not use the same regex engine as C#, and if you do use it, I suggest putting on multiline

Comment: ah ok I see, Is there any reason why I should not use my regex `\b\d+\w+` for matching an enum starting with a decimal and `\b_+\w+` for matching an enum starting with an underscore followed by a decimal? Those two are working as well, but regex is black magic so I better ask twice ;)

Comment: It will be a little slower, seeing that you know you just want to match the digit or underscore, and thats all we really care about then match that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple strategy is to deserialize the value into a `string` property and then convert into your own data type (enum or otherwise) via an accessor method or a secondary getter-only property.

Comment: Yes true, that would be the solution if I do not find a more elegant way. I was hoping to use somehow the Json.Net Pipeline for that (also for learning purposes)